# Connect to the switch console port, type the keyboard I will get messy code

Tags: switch, mac

I follow the [Tutorial](https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/how-to-use-a-mac-for-connecting-through-the-console-port/td-p/2392883) to connect a switch,

use `ls *usb*` I can find the usb:

```
$ ls *usb*
cu.wchusbserial1410   
tty.wchusbserial1410
```

I connect to it:

```
screen tty.wchusbserial1410 9600
```

but I get the messy code when I type the keyboard.

I type <kbd>enter</kbd>, there gets the `?`, I type <kbd>s</kbd>, there will get `f`. you can see in the snapshot:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

**EDIT-01**

My switch is Juniper-EX4300 and the usb driver is [Qinheng](http://www.wch.cn/products/category/1.html).

and the [Juniper manual](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/release-independent/junos/topics/task/installation/port-ex-series-mini-usb-management-console-connecting.html) shows the Baud rate is `9600`.

**EDIT-02**

I use the console-serial line connect the switch port, and then use the serial-USB convertor connect the line and my Mac.

Comment: This is because of speed mismatch between your console and the device you try to connect to. You have to know on which speed your device is communicating and set this speed to your terminal program. Also good to know is number of data-bits, stop-bits and parity.

Comment: @WinnieTigger Do you mean the switch's console port ?

Comment: Yes! On what speed etc. is the switch console set? This parameters need to be the same in your terminal programm.

Comment: how to see the switch console port? and in the manual the Juniper EX4300 is 9600, I use this rate connect you can see in my post.

Comment: Is this a new device? If not, maybe someone changed it.

Comment: @WinnieTigger I use the console-serial line connect the switch port, and then use the serial-USB convertor connect the line and my Mac.

Comment: Yes,of course. I just more related to cisco, but I connect the Cisco devices in the same way as you. So I really think it is a speed problem not cabling.

Comment: OK, I just have a look at the manual, now I want to know if you are using RJ45 cable or mini-USB cable to connect to the switch?

Comment: @WinnieTigger I use the RJ45 connect to it. you can see [more](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52143/macos-connect-to-the-juniper-ex4300).

Comment: That seems to be correct. Is this a new switch?

Comment: @WinnieTigger No, this is a second hand switch.

Comment: So I assume that the previous owner changed the speed of the console. Maybe you can try different speed settings in your terminal program.

Comment: My colleague use Windows and the same rate can connect it success.

Comment: OK, thats new information and will make sure that 9600 is the speed of your console. Unfortunately I don't know much about MAC-OS. So I think I can't help you anymore. I am really sorry!

Comment: Try this :  screen tty.wchusbserial1410 9600,cs8,-parenb,-cstopb,-hupcl

Comment: @Golgot Not work, bro.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin No, this not works for me, I tried this. I think this is caused by a wrong hardware module.

Answer (score 1):

Serial port settings mismatch. Please set serial setting as below:

- Baud rate—9600
- Flow control—None
- Data—8
- Parity—None
- Stop bits—1
- DCD state—Disregard

Comment: whats then command of the settings with ‘screen’?

Comment: try 9600,cs8,-ixon,-ixoff

Comment: this do not work, bro.